# Specifying logging options in forever JS config file

Tags: node.js, logging, configuration, forever

The [github readme of forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) states

> In addition to passing forever the path to a script (along with
>   accompanying options, described above), you may also pass forever the
>   path to a JSON file containing these options. For example, consider an
>   application with the following file structure:

In the following example, the options `uid`, `append`, `watch`, `script` and `sourceDir` are set. All of these are long versions of arguments to the `forever` command (with the short versions being `-a`, `-w`, `-s`).

My problem is: some of the options to `forever` don't have a long version, for example `-m`, `-l`, `-e`, `-o`. **How do I provide these options in my json configuration file?**

I've tried adding values to keys such as `"l"` and `"log"`, but this didn't achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems like the JSON properties for all shorthand options are listed [here](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/lib/forever/cli.js#L109). For example, the JSON property for `-p` would be `"path"`.

```
var argvOptions = cli.argvOptions = {
  'command':   {alias: 'c'},
  'errFile':   {alias: 'e'},
  'logFile':   {alias: 'l'},
  'killTree':  {alias: 't', boolean: true},
  'append':    {alias: 'a', boolean: true},
  'fifo':      {alias: 'f', boolean: true},
  'number':    {alias: 'n'},
  'max':       {alias: 'm'},
  'outFile':   {alias: 'o'},
  'path':      {alias: 'p'},
  'help':      {alias: 'h'},
  'silent':    {alias: 's', boolean: true},
  'verbose':   {alias: 'v', boolean: true},
  'watch':     {alias: 'w', boolean: true},
  'debug':     {alias: 'd', boolean: true},
  'plain':     {boolean: true},
  'uid':       {alias: 'u'}
};
```

Comment: Very useful! Shame that it is not included in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

logFile, outFile, errFile worked for me too. :)
in my case, I used : myapp_config.json

```
{
   "uid": "myapp",
   "append": true, 
   "watch": true,
   "script": "myscript.js",
   "sourceDir": "/home/myaccount/myproj/myapp",
   "logFile": "/home/myaccount/.forever/forever.log",      
   "outFile": "/home/myaccount/.forever/out.log",
   "errFile": "/home/myaccount/.forever/err.log"
}
```

usage: 
forever start myapp_config.json
forever stop myapp

Answer (score -1):

Try using these, they worked for me:
logFile, outFile, errFile